# Not able to connect Mulesoft > Services with Anypoint Platform

Tags: integration, configuration, mulesoft

I'm trying to do a POC and connect Mulesoft > Services (/lightning/setup/MulesoftServices/home) with Anypoint platform, but I haven't been able to do so, every time I try to connect to any instance (Trial / Paid) I see this error message.

I wondering if I'm missing a configuration or setup an step.

Thanks in advance

[image]